Training custom seq2seq transformer model without any tokenizer
I’m working on a custom seq2seq transformer model for translating between two sets of token IDs.
My input and translation token IDs range from 0 to 8191.
Example:
input_ids = [2034, 4043, ...., 3]  # length is 2048
translation_input_ids = [3042, 9123, ...., 3285]  # length is 2048

I’m using EncoderDecoderModel with BertConfig for both the encoder and decoder. My sequences are all of length 2048. Here are my questions:
Vocab Size: Given that my tokens range from 0 to 8191, do I need to set vocab_size to 8194 (i.e., 8192 + 2) to account for additional tokens like decoder_start_token_id and pad_token_id?
Handling decoder_start_token_id: How does the model handle the decoder_start_token_id? Is it correct to assign it to a value outside my token range (e.g., 8192)?
Padding Token: If I don’t need padding (since all my sequences are the same length), do I still need to provide a pad_token_id in the configuration?
Config Choice: Is using BertConfig the right approach for this task, or would something like BartConfig or T5Config be more appropriate?
Here is my current model structure:
batch_size = 2
vocab_size = 8192 + 2
embedding_size = 1024
context_window_length = 2048

device_num = 0
device = torch.device(f'cuda:{device_num}' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Initialize BertConfig for encoder and decoder with vocab_size=8192
config_encoder = BertConfig(
    vocab_size=vocab_size, 
    hidden_size=embedding_size, 
    num_hidden_layers=6, 
    num_attention_heads=8, 
    intermediate_size=embedding_size*4, 
    max_position_embeddings=context_window_length
)
config_decoder = BertConfig(
    vocab_size=vocab_size, 
    hidden_size=embedding_size, 
    num_hidden_layers=6, 
    num_attention_heads=8, 
    intermediate_size=embedding_size*4, 
    max_position_embeddings=context_window_length, 
    is_decoder=True, 
    add_cross_attention=True
)

config = EncoderDecoderConfig.from_encoder_decoder_configs(config_encoder, config_decoder)
model = EncoderDecoderModel(config=config)
model.config.decoder_start_token_id = 8192  # arbitrary number that is not between 0 and 8191
model.config.pad_token_id = 8193  # arbitrary number that is not between 0 and 8191
model.to(device)

Now when I run the model training, it the loss is stuck to 6.5 just after around 1000 iterations, (my epoch size is 19500 iterations) and stays over there.
Is this the correct way to run a seq2seq training without any tokenizer involved? Or am I doing something wrong here?
I do not need the tokenizer here because these sequence are coming directly from a generation process and those are not text. But do I still need to design a customer tokenizer to run with the BERTConfig?
